# typedef throwing error even with typename keyword

Tags: c++, typedef

The following C++ code:

```
template<typename State>
class Node
{
public:
    typedef typename State::Move Move;
...
}
```

says:

> > missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

I searched for the error message and everyone suggests adding `typename` keyword to the `typedef` line, which in my case is already there. What else am I supposed to do?

Comment: Are you sure thats the line with the error?

Comment: @tkausl: At least in that double-clicking the message takes me to this line.

Comment: Compiles for me: http://cpp.sh/2lqe5

Comment: This is C++ Windows Runtime Component project if that has anything to do with this error.

Comment: 10.7k rep and no MCVE?

Comment: @molbdnilo: Microsoft Certified what? :)

Comment: [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @molbdnilo: As I said, I'm not a C++ guy. I'm not sure how much of the C++ code I have would be enough for generating the problem. Pasting the entire class (300+ lines) here is generally disliked by many on SO.

Comment: In addition it also says `'Move': unknown override specifier` for the same line, if that would help in any way.

Comment: This really sounds like the problem is somewhere else, at least this short example looks fine, given the class passed as `State` actually _has_ a typename called `Move` (typedef or using).

Comment: Having too much code is no excuse for not creating an MCVE.   Remove code until the error disappears.  The last removed code is probably related to the error, so put it back.  Continue until you have the smallest example possible that actually demonstrates your problem.   In the process of creating the MCVE, you might have an "Aha!" moment, and realise what the problem is.   Otherwise, people will have a fighting chance of helping you .... which is not the case with your question as posted.

Comment: @tkausl: Let me ask a deeper question. How does C++ ensure that the generic parameter `State` will contain a type or member `Move`?

Comment: The same way it ensures that a type has `Move` when you use `type::Move` directly.

Comment: @tkausl: I think I get it. C++ templates are *very* different from my concept of generics. A template does not verify its parameters when the class is defined. Instead it checks them when we instantiate the class and pass in a type. Oh and that looks like the world is upside down.

Comment: Also, isn't the Runtime Components using [C++/CX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh755822.aspx), a totally different language?

Comment: @BoPersson: Yes, but the code does compile fine now (see my answer). I think it is only using common C++ syntax.

Comment: @BoPersson: Also I'd humbly disagree with the *totally different* statement. As far as the language syntax is concerned, I'd say it is over 90% similar to standard C++.

Comment: I wouldn't know, as I don't use any of the C++/whatever languages. And what if your problem lies in the 10% difference? :-) You might want to add the [tag:c++-cx] tag to reach a wider audience.

Comment: It's not a very good idea to start a question about C++ by bashing the language when you are hoping that C++ enthusiasts may help you in their spare time. If I were asking something about C# generics, I certainly would not begin with *"I'm not a C# guy and this generics system is spinning my head. Templates are so very straight forward in C++. Thanks C++ guys for not including this generics monster in the specs.*"

Comment: @ChristianHackl: Word taken. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone who helped. The problem was indeed somewhere else. Let me explain:

In C#, we use generics (which are rough equivalents of C++ templates system) in class definition and can apply constraints on them:

```
class Node<T> where T:SomeClass { ... }
```

which allows us to instantiate objects of type `T` inside this class. Those objects will have all members of `SomeClass` automatically. You get nice intellisense as a bonus too. Great thing about this system is that the integrity of this class can be verified at compile time without us having to instantiate an object of type `Node<T>`.

[*disclaimer: The following is my understanding. Correct me if I'm wrong.*]

C++ doesn't work this way. C++ will allow you to access anything against the template parameter (in my case it was `State::Move`). The templated class on its own doesn't/can't ensure that the template parameter will actually have a member named `Move`. Only when you instantiate an object of templated class, such as `Node<SomeType> x;`, it actually ensures that `SomeType` must contain a member named `Move` and throws error if that's not the case.

In my problem, I was instantiating an object of `Node` and passing it an `int` as template parameter, which obviously doesn't have any member named `Move`, so it was complaining (unfortunately pointing to a very wrong place, but that's another story). Replacing it with the appropriate type fixed the error for me.

Hope this helps someone down the road.

Comment: If you are really interested in underlying problems with C++ templates, whose power was not designed but discovered (sic!) to gar far beyond "container of T", then search for "C++ concepts" in Google. Concepts have not yet made it into the C++ standard, but I suppose they would make problems like the one here much easier to detect and fix.

Comment: @ChristianHackl: Just read C++ Concepts topic on wiki. This thing seems to be what C# generics already offer. no? i.e. parameter constraints, type deduction are already available in C# (and VB.NET). Or is it more than that?

Comment: Without being an expert on C# generics, I'd say the major difference is that C#'s generic constraints are limited to the object-oriented paradigma. For example, with your `where T:SomeClass`, you actually need a `SomeClass` base type somewhere and require your type arguments to derive from it. That's not the case with concepts, or with templates in general. For example, a concept could be used to explicitly state that some template function `void f(T)` is restricted to `T` with a `foo` member function, without any need for a `HasFooOperation` base class.

Comment: Further good reading here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15634970/what-makes-a-template-different-from-a-generic. I especially like this summary: *"the main difference is that templates define a turing complete language, functional in style although with a horrible grammar at it on which you can program."*